# C code format using <<

Tags: c, syntax, firmware

I dont understand why the "1<<5" in the following snippet of code, didn't find anything on google

```
gpio_output_set((1<<5), 0, (1<<5), 0);
```

Why not use 5? or 32? :)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you know the value of `1 << 5`? It's definitely not 5. Write several lines of code and check its value.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting

Comment: It's called a "shift" operator.  Specifically, this is a left-shift operator, and what it does is move (shift) the bits of the left argument (`1`) left a number of places (`100000` = 32)

Comment: I know about shift but didnt get it in this case, thanks, been most helpful

Comment: The real question is: 'why not use 0x20?'

Comment: why shift 2 literal numbers?

Comment: @WilliamPursell The `gpio` in the function name leads me to believe that `1 << 5` describes pin 5 of a general-purpose I/O port. In that case, it makes some sense to choose a representation that includes the pin number `5`.

Comment: @Wintermute that is correct, it does map to GPIO5 of the esp8266, sometimes defined as something else though, it makes sense now even though I didnt ask the correct question - thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of expression `1<<5` is equal to `32` and equivalent to `2 ^ 5` (in the mathematical notation)

Operator `<<` is bitwise left shift operator.

From the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros.

I think this record

```
gpio_output_set((1<<5), 0, (1<<5), 0);
```

was used instead of

```
gpio_output_set( 32, 0, 32, 0);
```

that to show how the value is obtained. But in any case it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 5.

Comment: `2 ^ 5` is an unfortunate choice in this context.

Comment: Because `^` is binary XOR in C. Try `2<sup>5</sup>` (directly in the markup, not between backticks).

Answer (score 2):

> "Why not use 32?"

Because nobody (including person who wrote the code, one year later) knows what `gpio_output_set(32)` means. 32 in this case would be what's known as a "magic number", which is programmer slang for a hard-coded number which just sits there in your code, with no rational explanation why, it just magically gets the job done. It is very bad programming practice.

`1<<5` on the other hand, is the industry de facto standard way of saying "bit number 5". The intention of the programmer is clear.

Always strive to write self-documenting code, whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting take

Comment: The pins are defined as BIT0 to BITX  so I would expect BIT5

Answer (score 1):

since 1<<5 is off-course a bit-wise operation, so it is far different from decimal 5.
The operation 1<<5 will give a decimal value of 32.